# drop column or re-create table using required column : which is better?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I need to drop around 200 columns (not indexed) from a table. The table contains huge records (around 3 million). I tried two different approaches to drop these columns :

1. Individually dropped the column using "alter table drop column ..." statement.
   Ex: ALTER TABLE AO_PO_DTL_SCHEDULE_BKP1 DROP (shipto_jurisdiction_code,mark_po_box,..);
   or
   ALTER TABLE AO_PO_DTL_SCHEDULE_BKP4 SET UNUSED (shipto_jurisdiction_code,mark_po_box,...)
   ALTER TABLE AO_PO_DTL_SCHEDULE_BKP4 DROP UNUSED COLUMNS;
2. Re-created the table with the required columns and imported the records from the original table.

But, both the approach taking long time to complete (around 30 min/table) and We have some 10 tables to do this activity within 4hr of downtime in prod environment.

I want to know Is there any different way I can use to drop these columns or if the above two are the only way then **what is the best way to drop these columns from the table:**

After drop do we have any command to Re-Organize the table structure ?
I am using oracle 11g. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If there are foreign keys or other dependencies drop column may be the only alternative.

Comment: @jarlh No there is no foreign key or any kind of relationship with the other tables and it has no Index available for the columns which are going to be dropped.

Comment: Do you have to drop them during the downtime - could you just mark them as unused? And then maybe drop them in batches in future maintenance windows? How many columns are left, are they heavily indexed, and are any of those used as foreign keys (not sure if you're saying there are no FKs, or that the columns being dropped aren't referenced)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to create a table from required columns from the particular table like below

```
create table sample_cpy 
as
select sno,name,dept from sample;
```

If you want only table structure use like below

```
create table sample_cpy 
as
select sno,name,dept from sample where rownum < 1;
```

These above methods won't create any `index,primary,foriegn key etc` .

If everthing seems ok then you can `delete` the source table.